# How to automatically upgarde a category in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

i am designing an application that as Students and Categories, the categories include

```
Level 100
Level 200
Level 300
Level 400
Level 500
```

and each user belongs to only one of this categories

What i want to achieve is that any student under a category e.g(100 Level)  will automatically m be promoted to the next category i.e (200 Level) after 365 days 
and also if a student reaches The highest Level i.e 500L, the promotion stops

Any way to do this ?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Changing the category? Determining whether 365 days have passed? Executing a task automatically?

Comment: THE PROBLEM IS CHANGING THE CATEGORY AUTOMATICALLY

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/pl/minor_differences/capslock

Comment: WHY IS IT ON HOLD, AS CLEARLY SEEN IN THE QUESTION,AFTER 365 DAYS each student under a category moves to the next category thats all i wanty to achieve e.g students in 100L moves to 200L

Answer (score 2):

I don't like much of `IF` and `ELSE`. Would have done it with something like making a Level order mapping, this can be pulled from your DB too, or make it according if you have a position column.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  LEVEL_ORDER = ["Level 100","Level 200","Level 300","Level 400", "Level 500"]

  def assign_next_level
     if (Time.now - created_at) > 365.days
        self.level = next_level  
     end
  end

   def next_level
     index =  LEVEL_ORDER.find_index(level)
     LEVEL_ORDER(index+1)
   end
end


#This will iterate over user and check if created > 365 will call the instance
# method  assign_next_level. Will save you from Harcoding Level
User.all.each do |user|
    user.assign_next_level
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a task for this, with the code something like below

```
User.all.each do |u|
  if ((Time.now - u.created_at) > 365.days) && u.level == Level 100)
  u.level = Level 200
  if ((Time.now - u.created_at) > 365.days) && u.level == Level 200)
  u.level = Level 300
  if ((Time.now - u.created_at) > 365.days) && u.level == Level 300)
  u.level = Level 400
  if ((Time.now - u.created_at) > 365.days) && u.level == Level 400)
  u.level = Level 500
end
```

Comment: Your `if`s need some `end`s

Comment: Yes sorry its my bad..there shud be elsif condition...